# python selenium css selector nth element

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I am trying to parse this code on selenium and basically want the first item from the list i.e "product one-col new"! clicked...

```
<ul id="product-list">

    <li class="product one-col new">
        <ul>
            <li class="image" title="one item 5">
                <a href="#product/0f37f703-ed9a-3d10-86c0-7d0c0fcdb9ec">
                    <img width="" height="" alt="" src="/content/images/ProductImages/you-are-here/3/E/4/3E42561208174E6FBC81A10CDAE48659.jpg"></img>
                    <span class="new"> … </span>
                    <span class="hover"></span>
                </a>
                <p class="retailer">

                    CHECK ME

                </p>
                <p class="brand"></p>
            </li>
            <li class="price"> … </li>
            <li class="name" title="one item 5"> … </li>
            <li class="first-seen"> … </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
    <li class="product one-col new"> … </li>
```

I have tried this

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul[id='product-list']  li:nth-of-type(1)").click()
```

but it does not work?

any idea?

**UPDATE**:

the correct path was

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#product-list > :first-child").text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want a direct child, so the selector should use the child combinator. Plus, there’s `:first-of-type`/`:first-child`:

```
#product-list > :first-child
```